# How to override a indirectly invoked method

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am not very sure how to title this question properly, I will just try to describe it as clear as I can : .

```
Interface InterfaceB {
  void methodB();
}

Class ClassB implements InterfaceB {
  void methodB() {
    //...
  }
}

Class ClassA {
  InterfaceB methodA() {
    return new ClassB();
  }
}
```

---

```
Class MyClass {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClassA a = new ClassA();
    InterfaceB b = a.methodA();
    b.methodB();  // override this guy
  }
}
```

I want to override methodB, without change ClassA and ClassB. Appreciate any ideas.

Comment: What do you mean by override here please?

Comment: You will be overriding methodB in class B in any case.

Comment: By saying overriding, I mean to change its behaviour. Just to high light again, I cannot change ClassA and ClassB.

Comment: In what way do you need to change its behavior? And why is it that you need to change the method's behavior, rather than, say, writing code that performs the different behavior and calling that instead of methodB? What if you write your own `InterfaceB` implementation that wraps the `b` object you got from `a.methodA()`?

Comment: @David See my answer. There is a way to override methodB without changing either class A or class B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you can do :

```
ClassA a = new ClassA() {//extend class A

 InterfaceB methodA() {//Override methodA
    return new ClassB() {//extend class B
       void methodB() {//Override methodB
       //...
       }
    };
  }
};
```

You have overidden methodB without changing either class A or class B. That being said, you don't really need to extend from ClassA. You could create a `factory`, pass it to ClassA as a dependency and pass a parameter to `methodA` telling it what concrete implementation of `classB` should be used to call `methodB`

Answer (score 1):

Since `methodA` of `ClassA` always returns an instance of `ClassB`, if you want to override `ClassB`'s `methodB`, you have to extend both ClassA and ClassB and override `methodA` and `methodB` in the sub-classes.

```
class ClassSubB extends ClassB {
  @Override
  void methodB() {
    //...
  }
}

class ClassSubA extends ClassA {
  @Override
  InterfaceB methodA() {
    return new ClassSubB();
  }
}
```

Now

```
class MyClass {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClassA a = new ClassSubA(); // create an instance of ClassSubA
    InterfaceB b = a.methodA(); // will return an instance of ClassSubB
    b.methodB();  // will call methodB of ClassSubB
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this the only way? because in my real situation, the hierarchy is far more complicated. In that case, I may need to extends so many stuff. Sigh.

Comment: @David You could take advantage of anonymous inner classes to reduce the number of .java files that you have to create. See my answer. That being said, there is no other solution other than creating subclasses of A on B regardless of whether you create .java files for your subclasses or use anonymous inner classes.

Comment: @bot i don't think there is no other solution. Please check my solution. You don't need to create a new class for A, just so that it could return the correct object of B.

Comment: @Pratik What happens when you have 10 different ways in which you want to override `methodB`.

Comment: You differentiate on a value rather than a boolean. Still better than creating 10 different subclasses just to provide the right object

Comment: Thank you all. Anyway, in my case, since I cannot change either ClassA or ClassB. So I applied the answer from bot. Of course, Eran's answer is also the same idea if I understand correctly. Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

```
Interface InterfaceB {
  void methodB();
}

Class ClassB implements InterfaceB {
  void methodB() {
    //...
  }
}

class ClassSubClassB extends ClassB {
@Override
void methodB() {
    //...
  }
}

Class ClassA {

  InterfaceB methodA(boolean overriddenMethod) {
if(overriddenMethod)
    return new ClassSubClassB();
else
    return new ClassB();
  }
}
Class MyClass {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClassA a = new ClassA();
    InterfaceB b = a.methodA(true);
    b.methodB();  // override this guy
  }
}
```

This would work without having to override classA.
Ideally you should be creating a factory class, where you would delegate the job of object creation. So you would create the required instances based on certain conditions.

Comment: I mean to override the methodB defined in ClassB.

Comment: In order to override methodB in class B, you will have to subclass B and use that subclass.

Comment: I cannot change both classA and classB, they are not my classes.

Comment: Then you would have to go with @Eran's solution.